# Сортировка словаря python по возрастанию

Tags: python, сортировка

Имеется нижеуказанный код, который ищет частоту появления слов в тексте. Как можно отсортировать результат по степени возрастания частот и вывести на экран?

```
import codecs
import re
import string

frequency = {}
document_text = open(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Машинное обучение\222.txt")
text_string = document_text.read().lower()
match_pattern = re.findall(r'\b[a-z]{3,15}\b', text_string)

for word in match_pattern:
    count = frequency.get(word,0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1

frequency_list = frequency.keys()
words = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, words)


for words in frequency_list:
    print (words, frequency[words])
```

Comment: `sorted(frequency.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: @MaxU `reverse=True` здесь не надо. sorted() по возрастанию по умолчанию сортирует.